Next.js exits immediately after "Compiling /..."
When running npm run dev on a Next.js project with Fluent UI React installed, it exits instantly after either "Compiling /..." or "Compiled / in (x) seconds".
@GavinGoGaming ➜ /workspaces/MuiTestProjects/glacier-client (main) $ npm run dev

> fluent-test@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

  ▲ Next.js 13.5.4
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000

 ✓ Ready in 2s
 ○ Compiling /page ...

@GavinGoGaming ➜ /workspaces/MuiTestProjects/glacier-client (main) $ 

Using a gh codespace and have tried almost every solution i could find out on the internet.
Heres my dependencies:
"dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "8.117.0",
    "@fluentui/react-components": "9.48.0",
    "@uidotdev/usehooks": "^2.4.1",
    "next": "13.5.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-rnd": "10.4.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.12.7",
    "typescript": "5.4.5"
  }

I tried running, reinstalling modules, deleting node_modules, changing versions, and nothing fixed the issue.

UPD: If anybody else is having this error, try rebooting your codespace or waiting for github to close it before re-opening it. If your not on a codespace, restart your computer or do something to lower memory/CPU usage.
